# <%= yield %> not inserting page content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I am doing my customary revision on updating to a new rails version. I am using Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Rails 5) by Michael Hartl. I am building his sample_app. `application.html.erb` as expected has a `<%= yield %>` call, it is not inserting page content. Has anybody any idea why this is happening?

The terminal shows: Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatc‌​h/middleware/templat‌​es/rescues/routing_e‌​rror.html.erb within rescues/layout when I try to load a page.

This is application.html.erb

```
<`!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title> 
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %> 
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> 
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> 
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %> 
    <%= yield %> 
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %> 
  </body> 
</html>`
```

Comment: You get errors? Something is displayed?

Comment: @gleb List your `application.html.erb` code

Comment: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>

  </head>

  <body>
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

  
    <%= yield %>
  
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>'

Comment: The terminal shows: Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout   when I try to load a page

Comment: Can you please show us your controller / view and routes.eb. It seems to have something to do with your routes.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the app and stole the `application.html.erb` I put it in the original app. It worked!! Out of curiosity I replaced the original `application.html.erb`  and, it worked ??????